# How do i generate text from ids in Torchtext's sentencepiece_numericalizer?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, bert, transformer

The torchtext `sentencepiece_numericalizer()` outputs a generator with indices SentencePiece model corresponding to token in the input sentence. From the generator, I can get the ids.

My question is how do I get the text back after training?

For example

```
>>> sp_id_generator = sentencepiece_numericalizer(sp_model)
>>> list_a = ["sentencepiece encode as pieces", "examples to   try!"]
>>> list(sp_id_generator(list_a))
    [[9858, 9249, 1629, 1305, 1809, 53, 842],
     [2347, 13, 9, 150, 37]]
```

How do I convert `list_a` back t(i.e `"sentencepiece encode as pieces", "examples to try!"`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Torchtext does not implement this, but you can use directly the [SentencePiece package](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece/blob/master/python/README.md). installable from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/sentencepiece/).

```
import sentencepiece as spm
sp = spm.SentencePieceProcessor(model_file='test/test_model.model')
sp.decode([9858, 9249, 1629, 1305, 1809, 53, 842])
```